# VoIP free SDK for Web, Android and iOS for Video Calling and Chatting

Tags: android, ios, web, voip, ejabberd

I tried searching but with no avail. What is the easiest way to establish it? 
Requirement is I should be able to call or message from any plateform (iOS, Android or Web).

I did establish my XMPP/Jabber server for chatting (single and grouped) but I am unable to find any help for free video calling.

Some nice suggestions are needed, I can still change/trash all the things I have done yet.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to call a contact in XMPP world, you need to look for a client supporting the [XMPP Jingle](http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/technology-overview/jingle/) protocol. You can find a list of client supporting Jingle here: http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/technology-overview/jingle/#impl-client